# Is there shorthand to create an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

After I get the result from the recordset, I'm shortening the name for easier writing in the page. I'm echoing $TitleTarg[1] thru $TitleTarg[100]. It's all working, but is there a shorthand for this so I don't have to write it 100 times? It's used in many pages.

```
$TitleTarg = array(
'1'=>$row_rsTargTitles['description1'],
'2'=>$row_rsTargTitles['description2'],
'3'=>$row_rsTargTitles['description3'],
'4'=>$row_rsTargTitles['description4'],
'5'=>$row_rsTargTitles['description5],

ad nauseum to 100
);
```

I've been reading for three hours and checked the 'Similar Questions' section to no avail. Working answers are appreciated and up-voted.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: How are you generating this array? Manually? Programmatically?

Comment: I'm generating it manually.

Comment: I've been doing that all morning and it's not working as I thought it would. I don't understand why. It doesn't produce a result in the page.

Comment: @kingkero - okay so now it wants to play correctly. I'll peruse this a bit and get back to you. I need to compare your correct answer to my broken code. Thanks, I'll let you know in a bit.

Comment: @kingkero - Please post this as an answer instead of a comment so I can upvote it. Maybe someone else can benefit from my error of the missing [$i] on $TitleTarg. And thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your source's keys are always `descriptionN` with `N` being a number counted upward without skipping one, this could easily be done with a simple `for` loop like this

```
$TitleTarg = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    $TitleTarg[$i] = $row_rsTargTitles['description'.$i];
}
```

Make sure you have the correct limits (start and end).

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this through easy code

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) 
{ 
    $temp = 'description'.$i;
    $TitleTarg[$i] = '$row_rsTargTitles['.$temp.']'; 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($TitleTarg);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. kingkero nailed it elegantly and it works brilliantly.

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER ..No problem..Goal is to resolved the question.. :)